# Doctrine 1 installed with Composer is not working

Tags: php, doctrine, composer-php

I'm trying to integrate Composer into an older PHP app which is running on a server that only supports 5.2.  The app was written with Zend Framework 1 and Doctrine 1.  After performing the relevant integration and trying the assorted packages available on composer I get errors upon running the app:

```
PHP Warning:  include(Doctrine.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [...]/www/dispatcher.php on line 11
[Sun Oct 21 12:33:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Doctrine.php' for inclusion (include_path='[...]/application/library:[...]/vendor/digital-canvas/zend-framework/library:.:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:[...]/app/application/../library:[...]/application/../ext') in [...]/www/dispatcher.php on line 11
```

It certainly appears that the issue is that the include_path isn't modified to include the location for Doctrine.  The `include_paths.php` file in the Composer directory only shows:

```
return array(
    $vendorDir . '/digital-canvas/zend-framework/library',
);
```

and I've noticed none of the `composer.json` files in the Doctrine 1 packages include a `include-path` directive which I'm assuming would be what modifies that file.  Am I missing something?  Are these packages slightly broken and require an explicit include to start the ball rolling?

Adding the proper dir to the array above *does* fix the issue.  But I don't want to have to touch generated files and I'm hoping there's some subtlety to the problem that I'm missing rather than needing to either implement a workaround or figure out how to repair the published packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case is that Doctrine itself does not seem to depend on the include_path, but ZF1 does, so I would recommend you just add that path in the include path of your project like this:

```
{
    "include-path": ["vendor/doctrine/doctrine1/lib"]
}
```

Then use `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising.  I'd like to avoid the hard wired path so I'll be looking at hooking into Composer or at least its configuration files, but that won't be any time too soon.

Comment: It's just a relative path from your composer.json, and it's not like it'll change since it is just your vendor dir + the package name which are both fairly constant in time and across machines. It's really not very risky.

Comment: I was misreading where that config was going (I was thinking it was outside of composer).  That direction should work well.